# Suggested tag synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

Some tag synonyms that I think should be implemented. There are more, I just didn't go through the whole alphabet yet. Feel free to add to the list.

1. [advertisements](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/advertisements)->[ads](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ads)
2. [applet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applet)->[applets](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/applets)
3. [argument](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/argument)->[arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/arguments)
4. [at](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/at)->[at-commands](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/at-commands)
5. [attachment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/attachment)->[attachments](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/attachments)
6. [bat](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bat)->[cmd-script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd-script)
7. [black-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/black-screen)->[black-screen-of-death](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/black-screen-of-death)
8. [bot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bot)->[bots](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bots)
9. [button](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/button)->[buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/buttons)
10. [camcorder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/camcorder)->[camera](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/camera)
11. [captcha](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/captcha)->[captchas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/captchas)
12. [chromium-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chromium-os)->[google-chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os)
13. [cloud-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage)->[online-backup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/online-backup)
14. [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line)->[commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/commandline)
15. [computer-system](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-system)->[pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pc)
16. [corrupt](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/corrupt)->[corruption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/corruption)
17. [cut-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cut-paste)->[cut-and-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cut-and-paste)
18. [disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disc)->[cd-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd-rom)
19. [encrypted](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encrypted)->[encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encryption)
20. [ecyption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ecyption)->[encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encryption)

As an aside, there are a few here that are of the format `word -> words`. It would probably be a good idea to do those and the ones I didn't find like that automatically.

Comment: Are these being done, are they a bad idea...?

Comment: @slhck Can you go through these? some of them (like "bot" & "bots" or "advertisements" and "ads") really make sense.

Comment: @tempy Will do that later!

Comment: @tempy Most of these already existed. I didn't merge cloud storage and online backup, as well as disc and CD-ROM; the latter would need a manual retag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of these look good. However:

- ## 4: no. They're different things.
- ## 6 should probably be -> [batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch), a better-established tag. (Maybe synonym [cmd-script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd-script) to [batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch)?)
- ## 13: no. Online backup is just one use of cloud storage.
- ## 14: should go other direction
- ## 15: what about ARM-based systems?
- ## 18: no. Should be [disc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disc) -> [optical-media](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/optical-media); CD is too specific.
- ## 20: unnecessary; uncommon misspelling